# Typescript and react-router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, typescript-typings

trying to get up and running with react-router on typescript.  I have installed @types/react-router, but I am having an issue with an error that reads:

```
@types/react-router/index"' has no exported member 'hashHistory'
```

I have been trying different versions of router and the types.  My current versions are:

```
react:  16.3.2
react-router: 4.2.0
@types/react-router: 4.0.23
```

I have looked at the typings project on [github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-router). The index.ds.ts does not show `hashHistory` being exported.  However, there is a v3 folder, and the index.ds.ts there does.

I'm hoping that I just having found that magical mixture of versions for all involved packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react-router 4, there are separate packages for web, native and core. 
You need to install `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router` ([docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router))

Also,

> With React Router v4, one of the big changes is that there are a number of different router components. Each one will create a history object for you. The `<BrowserRouter>` creates a browser history, the `<HashRouter>` creates a hash history...

So instead of passing a history object to the Router, you can just use the HashRouter.

```
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

[Documentation on HashRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md)